# How to convert this var string to URL in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I need url filepath be a [URL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url) (NSURL in old versions of Swift). I have this:

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
        .documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)

// NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
let documentsDirectory = paths[0] as String

var filePath:String? = nil
var fileNamePostfix = 0
repeat {
    filePath =
    "\(documentsDirectory)/\(dateTimePrefix)-\(fileNamePostfix).mp4"
    fileNamePostfix += 1
} while (FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath))
```

I need to convert this to URL for use in `self.fileOutput.startRecording(to: <#outputFileURL: URL?#>, recordingDelegate: <#AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate?#>)` method.

I tried `filePath as? URL()` but it isn't correct.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

you need to do:

```
let fileUrl = URL(string: filePath)
```

or

```
let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
```

depending on your needs. See [URL docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url)

Before Swift 3, URL was called NSURL.

Comment: Swift 4: first one gives nil, second one works for paths like "/dir/file.ext". Thank you!

Comment: Why is this the case? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 16):

In swift 3 use:

`let url = URL(string: "Whatever url you have(eg: https://google.com)")`

Comment: thanks , it worked for me , earlier I was using         URL.init(fileURLWithPath: <#T##String#>)
which was producing wrong url. I think thats for some file path.

Answer (score 11):

in swift 4 to convert to url use URL

```
let fileUrl = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
```

or

```
let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
```

Answer (score 9):

In Swift3:
`let fileUrl = Foundation.URL(string: filePath)`

Comment: This will return `nil` if the path contains strings! Use `let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)` instead.

Comment: @natev not if the fileURL string contains the scheme `"file://"` as well if it was obtained using `absoluteString` instead of the `path` property.

Answer (score 4):

To Convert file path in String to NSURL, observe the following code

```
var filePathUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
```

Comment: please, try to explain it as well in short.