# Converting string (Contains json string) to NSURL in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have `PAI` its Implemented in `.NET`.

one of the web service url is like this

```
http://123.321.33/UploadCitizenImage?jsonString={\"Mobile\":\"12345678\", \"fileName\":\"7661832460_05072018.png\"}
```

while converting above string to URL in `swift`, app going `crash`.

for more info check this
[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: You have a space after a ",", it's not valid. You need to percent escape some characters.

Comment: This is _not_ a duplicate of [How to convert this var string to NSURL in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410473/how-to-convert-this-var-string-to-nsurl-in-swift) as this question is about _why does it crash?_

Answer (score 2):

The `URL(string:)` initializer returns an *optional* since the parsing of the string may fail. In that case, `nil` is returned. That's exactly what's happening here since the string you are providing is not a valid URL: there are several characters in the query that are not allowed there and need to be replaced: `{` as `%7B`, `"` as `%22`, space as `%20` and `}` as `%7D`.

So the initializer returns `nil`. Next thing you do is *force unwrap* via the `!` operator. But force-unwrapping a `nil` is illegal and is why you get the crash.

If you want to create an URL, please look into the [URLComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents) class which does all the necessary escaping for you so you don't need to care about it. The `queryItems` property is of particular interest for you, it's an array of [URLQueryItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlqueryitem).

Answer (score 1):

Please do something like that,

```
let jsonString = "jsonString={\"Mobile\":\"12345678\", \"fileName\":\"7661832460_05072018.png\"}" as String
let urlEncoadedJson = jsonString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:.urlHostAllowed)
let urls = NSURL(string:"http://123.321.33/UploadCitizenImage?\(urlEncoadedJson ?? "")")
```

First convert your json into encodedJson then add into your url.
Do let me know if there is some issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
let string = "http://123.321.33/UploadCitizenImage?jsonString={\"Mobile\":\"12345678\", \"fileName\":\"7661832460_05072018.png\"}"
let escapedString = string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
let url = URL(string: escapedString!)!
print(url)
```

Output will be like this,

```
http://123.321.33/UploadCitizenImage?jsonString=%7B%22Mobile%22:%2212345678%22,%20%22fileName%22:%227661832460_05072018.png%22%7D
```